# @param javadoc on class

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

My eclipse with following Code Templates -> Comments -> Types:

```
/**
 * @author ${user}
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
```

When I have a class

```
public class MyProtocol<T extends ProtocolContext> extends Protocol<ExtendProtocolContext> {
```

When I add comments to class

```
/**
 * @author user
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
```

I didn't find `@param` used in **class** in [How to Write Doc Comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137868.html)

> @param (methods and constructors only)

On on methods as

> ```
>   * @param text  the text of the tool tip
>   */
>   public void setToolTipText(String text) {
> ```

Should `@param` exists on classes also? if not is it Eclipse issue?

Comment: Your class is generic so it could be used to document the parameter of the genericity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@param

It should be used for classes too:

```
/**
  * @param <E> Type of element stored in a list
  */
 public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
 }
```

It is the same in the latest documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/doc-comment-spec.html

Comment: Thank you for the correct links